# SwiftUI: @ObservedObject redraws every view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I try to implement the MVVM way correctly in SwiftUI, so I came up with this (simplified) Model and ViewModel:

```
struct Model {
    var property1: String
    var property2: String
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var model = Model(property1: "this is", property2: "a test")

}
```

Using this in a `View` works fine, but I experienced some bad performance issues, as I extended the `ViewModel` with some computed properties and some functions (as well the `Model` itself is more complicated). But let's stay with this example, because it demonstrates perfectly, what I think is a big problem in SwiftUI itself.

Imagine, you have those views to display the data:

```
struct ParentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        print("redrawing ParentView")
        return ChildView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        print("redrawing ChildView")
        return VStack {
            ViewForTextField(property: self.$viewModel.model.property1)
            ViewForTextField(property: self.$viewModel.model.property2)
        }
    }

}

struct ViewForTextField: View {

    @Binding var property: String

    var body: some View {
        print("redrawing textView of \(self.property)")
        return TextField("...", text: self.$property)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }

}
```

Now entering text into one of the `TextField` leads to a redraw of *every* `View` in my window! The print output is:

```
redrawing ParentView
redrawing ChildView
redrawing textView of this is
redrawing textView of a test
redrawing ParentView
redrawing ChildView
redrawing textView of this isa
redrawing textView of a test
redrawing ParentView
redrawing ChildView
redrawing textView of this isab
redrawing textView of a test
...
```

As I can see, SwiftUI redraws *every* view, because every view is listening to the `ObservedObject`.

How can I tell SwiftUI, that it only should redraw those views, where really happened any changes?

Answer (score 1):

If all your views observe the same thing, and that thing changes, then all your views will re-render. This is by definition. There's no option to configure to optionally update certain views.

That being said, you can work around it by manipulating what changes you'd like to publish.

E.g.;

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var model = Model(property1: "this is", property2: "a test")
    var mytext = "some text" // pass this as binding instead of model.propertyX
}
```

Now when textfield changes, `mytext` changes, but this change won't be published thus won't trigger further view updates. And you still can access it from view model.

I personally would recommend using [@State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) and [@EnvironmentObject](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) instead of "view model". They are the built-in way to handle binding and view updates with tons of safe-guards and supports.

Also you should use value type instead of reference type as much as possible. MVVM from other languages didn't take this into consideration.

Comment: I think you're right that traditional MVVM is not the right approach for SwiftUI. The problem is that a fat ViewModel at the top causes the entire view hierarchy to be redrawn on every `@Published` change.

Answer (score 0):

Actually MVVM means own model for every view, which is updated on model changes, not *one* model for all views.

So there is no needs to observe `viewModel` in `ParentView` as it does not depend on it

```
struct ParentView: View {

    var viewModel: ViewModel // << just member to pass down in child

    var body: some View {
        print("redrawing ParentView")
        return ChildView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
    }
}
```

Alternate is to decompose view model so every view has own view sub-model, which would manage updates of own view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case I have different ChildViews arranged like a TabbedView and they all need access to the Model, so I need to have one big model that I can pass to the views. But I will try if I can split them...

Comment: By the way, your code doesn't change the main problem: ChildView will still be redrawn and that should not happen, if I split the views into container

Answer (score 0):

Something should be clarified here: when the SwiftUI framework loads your views, that doesn’t mean they’re necessarily being redrawn. Your swiftui views are not drawing code, they’re instructions for the SwiftUI framework.

SwiftUI loads your views, compares the viewids and selectively redraws what has changed. See the WWDC video on View Identities for a better explanation.