# SwiftUI ObservedObject makes view pop on update

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why is my view going back to the parent when the `ObservedObject` updates? I understand that the update to it redraws the view (and presumably also the `ParentView`) but frankly atm that I am looking at the `ChildView` I don't care about the look of the `ParentView`.

I would understand the behaviour if the displayed stuff was coming directly from the `ParentView` but it is tied to a class. Is this intended behaviour from Apple?

How am I supposed to manipulate Data in a View that got called by a `NavigationLink` without popping the view?

Why is this pop forced?
Is there a way to "hold it back"?

I've tried something like this:
[SwiftUI: @ObservedObject redraws every view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480230/swiftui-observedobject-redraws-every-view) but it didn't help. It just made it worse as I `tap` remove items anymore.

I have a code construct like this:

Parent View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var data = Data()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack() {
                ForEach(self.data.myArray, id: \.self) { subArray in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Child(data: self.data, mySubArray: subArray)) {
                        Text(subArray[0]).padding().background(Color.yellow)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child:

```
struct Child: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var data: Data
    var mySubArray: Array<String>
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(self.mySubArray, id: \.self) { str in
            Text(str).padding().background(Color.yellow)
                .onTapGesture {
                self.data.removeFromSubArray(index: self.data.myArray.firstIndex(of: self.mySubArray) ?? 0, remove: str)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And an ObservableObject:

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var myArray: Array<Array<String>> = []
    
    init() {
        self.myArray.append(["A", "B", "C"])
        self.myArray.append(["D", "E", "F"])
        self.myArray.append(["G", "H", "I"])
    }
    
    func removeFromSubArray(index: Int, remove: String) {
        if self.myArray.count-1 >= index {
            if let subIndex = self.myArray[index].firstIndex(of: remove) {
                self.myArray[index].remove(at: subIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you use array as id, which changes in your child view you could change it to: `ForEach(self.data.myArray.indices)` and use index to address your subarrays.

Comment: Ever get an update on this? There are some answers here as well that could be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665369

Comment: any update on this? I'm having this exact same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not no. The thing is: you should have a View Model for every View so this issue should not come up in the first place. Do you know what I mean? If not I can post an answer here to explain it better.